# Is there a way to trigger authentication from Spring boot running on Websphere 9.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, websphere

I have a simple Spring Boot REST api deployed on Websphere 9.0.

This API has a login endpoint that should trigger the authentication flow within Websphere.

When I am using basic authentication with specifying jee() tag in SecurityConfig everything works fine. Even the roles are mapped properly. Hence the preAuthentication part is working. However I would like to use my custom login endpoint instead of basic auth.

E.g:

POST /auth/login
{“username” : “something, “password” : “something”}

I already tried to invoke

```
import javax.http.HttpServletRequest;
... 
@PostMapping("/auth/login")
public void login(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
   request.login("something", "something");
}
...
```

but this triggers the DaoAuthenticationProvider and not the authentication provider within Websphere itself.

Any help would be appreciated. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way:

```
import com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest;

@PostMapping("/auth/login")
public void login(SRTServletRequest request) throws   ServletException { 
   request.login("something", "something");
}
```